# iOS AppStore update with localization will break the app?

Tags: ios, localization, app-store, installation

Hello guys this is a very important questions and I couldn't find a definitive answer anywhere, I believe many people passed through this situation so maybe you can help me.

I released my app and the first version was not localized at all, now I published an update that contain localizations, because of that some pictures, plists and even xibs are now out of their previous folders and placed inside the en.lproj etc.
The problem is, at least when testing with xCode, when the app is updated, the files from the previous installations are NOT removed, what causes the app to pick the old version of the files ( the ones in the non localized folder ), which causes some parts of the app to remain unlocalized and even causing it to crash in some situations.

I read that when updating through the AppStore the proccess will be different and the previous installation will be cleared out and so it will work properly, however I'm not sure and I really really don't want to release a buggy version of the app to public.

So someone have anything to say about this situation?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

In short you will not face this problem with actual update.

To test
Upload your new version of app (adhoc build) to [testflight](https://testflightapp.com) and update your older app from testflight.